# Checking to see if two cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to see if two cells are **NOT** empty in VBA. I'm using the `IsEmpty()` but I don't think I'm using them right. This is what I have. It's not working because it will always go into the if statement.

Inside my `if`, I'm manipulating some cells. I shouldn't manipulate them if I go into the else.(Which does nothing), but they end up changing also.

```
For i = 2 To rows 
        If ((Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4))) And (Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)))) Then
            'Do stuff...
        else
            'Do nothing...
        end if
next i
```

Is this the best way?

Comment: *I don't think I'm using them right* - is it not working? and what's not working about it? You can simply by reversing the logic and using `Len` (which seems to work better)... `If Len(Cells(i,4)) = 0 and Len(Cells(i,5)) = 0 Then 'do nothing Else 'do stuff End If`

Comment: `If Cells(i, 4) <> "" And Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then`

Answer (score 1):

These are all valid

> If ((Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 4))) And (Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 5)))) Then
>
> If Cells(i, 4) <> "" And Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
>
> If Len(Cells(i, 4)) And Len(Cells(i, 5)) Then
>
> If Len(Cells(i, 4)) > 0  And Len(Cells(i, 5)) > 0 Then

My personal preference is to use Len().  I think it's a clean look.

Wrapping your code in a with statement will make it easier to compare ranges on different worksheets.

```
With managerSheet

    For i = 2 To rows 
            If  Len(.Cells(i, 4)) And Len(.Cells(i, 5) Then
                'Do stuff...
            else
                'Do nothing...
            end if
    next i

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was not my if statement but rather the scope of my calls.
I forgot to include the scope of cells. `managerSheet.Cells(i, 4).. etc`
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The method I normally go for is to check the cell referenced, to a type. As far as I'm aware, when you reference a cell, the interpreter will return a type which best suits the value, i.e. `1` returns a `Double`, `"abc"` returns a `String` and so on. When a cell is blank, the type returned is `Empty`.

I carried out a performance test using the technique mentioned [here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1602/profiling-and-optimizing-vba.aspx).

Test 1: Using `Len()` to compare the cells took 40.9080069854244

```
dTime = MicroTimer
For i = 1 To 10000
  If Len(Cells(i, 4)) And Len(Cells(i, 5)) Then
    'Do something
  Else
    'Do nothing  
  End If
Next i
dTime = MicroTimer - dTime '40.9080069854244
```

Test 2: Comparing the cells to the type `Empty` only took 21.0493610010926

```
dTime = MicroTimer
For i = 1 To 10000
  If Cells(i, 4) <> Empty And Cells(i, 5) <> Empty Then
    'Do something
  Else
    'Do nothing
  End If
Next i
dTime = MicroTimer - dTime '21.0493610010926
```

It may not look as clean, but if definitely has a benefit.